# TensorFlow : Eval Never ends despite starting queue runners

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

My code hangs on the following statement:

```
print('Beginning Eval...')
feed_dict_train = {img_data: images_batch.eval(session=session),
                   img_labels: labels_batch.eval(session=session)}
```

I have tried to eval with both a single example and as a batch. The code to understand how images_batch and labels_batch are created is as follows:

Creating a single example:

```
def read_single_example(filename):
#Mini-init
image_size = 256
filenames = tf.train.string_input_producer([filename], num_epochs = None)
reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
_, serialized_example = reader.read(filenames)
features = tf.parse_single_example(
    serialized_example,
    features={
        'label':tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.float32),
        'image':tf.FixedLenFeature([image_size*image_size*3], tf.float32)
    })
label = features['label'] 
#label = tf.get_default_session().run(label)
image_data = features['image']
#image_data = tf.get_default_session().run(image_data)
image = tf.reshape(image_data,(256,256,3))
return label, image
```

Reading a single example:

```
label_train, image_train = read_single_example(path)
```

Batching the examples inside the training loop:

```
print('Getting Batch')
images_batch, labels_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch(
    [image_train, label_train], batch_size=batch_size,
    capacity=2000,
    min_after_dequeue=1000)
```

The records read from disk were created with the code found [here](https://gist.github.com/xmaayy/707e8fb5df2d9745623a49f64709e6bf) but in essence are just a bunch of 256x256x3 images with a 1x41 tensor for labels. Thats what I think I did anyway, hoping the records arent where I made the error or I have like 100GB of dead data.

This is how the Tf session is started:

```
session = tf.Session()
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
session.run(init)
tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=session)
```

Which to my understanding was all I needed to do to make everything work as intended. A gist of the full code for the network can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/xmaayy/5f0506f2c90ad71af17ba8905a05fe55). Hope I didnt do anything stupid, and thanks for the help!